# How to use ast.literal_eval in a pandas dataframe and handle exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a `dataframe` with a column containing a `tuple` data as a string. Eg. `'(5,6)'`. I need to convert this to a tuple structure. One way of doing it is using the ast.literal_eval(). I am using it in this way.

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Unfortunately, my data in this column contains empty strings also. The `ast.literal_eval()` is not able to handle this. I get this error.

`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

I am unsure if this is because it is unable to handle such a character. Based on my reading, I found that `ast.literal_eval()` works only in cases when a list, dict or tuple is there inside a string structure.

To overcome this I tried to create my own function and return an empty string if it raises an exception.

```
def literal_return(val):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(val)
    except ValueError:
        return (val)

df['Column2'] = df['Column'].apply(literal_return)
```

Even in this case, the same error pops up. How do we handle this. It would be great even if there is a way to ignore certain rows to apply the function and apply on the rest. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the DataFrame, just so we can verify the empty strings are the issue?

Comment: My apologies for the fact that I might not be able to do that. I am saying its because of that since I looked at the dataset and I could not find any other type of data in that column. Again, don't take me wrong

Comment: I think my workaround is correct and just that I did not handle exception for Syntax error. Once I did that, it works fine. My apologies again for not being able to post the example

Comment: In the `except` statement remove `ValueError` and return some empty string`''` or `null` inside it. I think it may solve your problem for now. For the correct solution we may require more details on the dataset.

Answer (score 15):

I would do it simply requiring a string type from each entry:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['column_2'] = df.column_1.apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

If You need to advanced Exception handling, You could do, for example:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(str(x))   
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return []

df['column_2'] = df.column_1.apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Comment: FYI, you can use the function without wrapping it in a lambda: `df.column_1.apply(f)`

Answer (score 3):

This works when the function is changed to:

```
def literal_return(val):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(val)
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError) as e:
        return val
```