# Removing characters from the dataframe python

Tags: python

I want to replace a str from one of the column from the table. example: i want to remove b"SET and b"MULTISET from the df column. how to achieve that.
I need output like
Details are as below,

```
columns = ['cust_id', 'cust_name', 'vehicle', 'details', 'bill'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=t, columns=columns)
df
    
        cust_id     cust_name                   vehicle                             details                                                 bill
0   101         b"SET{'Tom','C'}"           b"MULTISET{'Toyota','Cruiser'}"     b"ROW('Street 1','12345678','NewYork, US')"             1200.00
1   102         b"SET{'Rachel','Green'}"    b"MULTISET{'Ford','se'}"            b"ROW('Street 2','12344444','Florida, US')"             2400.00
2   103         b"SET{'Chandler','Bing'}"   b"MULTISET{'Dodge','mpv'}"          b"ROW('Street 1','12345555','Georgia, US')"             601.10
```

Required Output:

```
    cust_id     cust_name                   vehicle                             details                                         bill
0   101         {'Tom','C'}                 {'Toyota','Cruiser'}            ('Street 1','12345678','NewYork, US')               1200.00
1   102         {'Rachel','Green'}          {'Ford','se'}                   ('Street 2','12344444','Florida, US')               2400.00
2   103         {'Chandler','Bing'}         {'Dodge','mpv'}                 ('Street 1','12345555','Georgia, US')               601.10
```

Comment: ``print(t)`` and include output  in the post.

Comment: output of print(df)  is as below,                                                                                               cust_id
cust_name
vehicle
details
bill
0
101
b"SET{'Tom','C'}"
b"MULTISET{'Toyota','Cruiser'}"
b"ROW('Street 1','12345678','NewYork, US')"
1200.00
1
102
b"SET{'Rachel','Green'}"
b"MULTISET{'Ford','se'}"
b"ROW('Street 2','12344444','Florida, US')"
2400.00
2
103
b"SET{'Chandler','Bing'}"
b"MULTISET{'Dodge','mpv'}"
b"ROW('Street 1','12345555','Georgia, US')"
601.10

Comment: Hi Sushanth,  sorry i got confused and pasted print(df) output ..                                                                            print(t) output is as below,                                                                                                    [(101, b"SET{'Tom','C'}", b"MULTISET{'Toyota','Cruiser'}", b"ROW('Street 1','12345678','NewYork, US')", 1200.0), (102, b"SET{'Rachel','Green'}",  and goes on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution,

- Let's define column of interest,

```
columns = ['cust_name', 'vehicle', 'details']
```

- Use regex expression to extract values between `{}` or `()`

```
regex_ = r"([\{|\(].*[\}|\)])"
```

- Putting together, `str.decode('ascii')` is to convert columns values from `byte` to `string`.

```
columns = ['cust_name', 'vehicle', 'details']

regex_ = r"([\{|\(].*[\}|\)])"

for col in columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.decode('ascii').str.extract(regex_)
```

---

```
   cust_id            cust_name  ...                                details    bill
0      101          {'Tom','C'}  ...  ('Street 1','12345678','NewYork, US')  1200.0
1      102   {'Rachel','Green'}  ...  ('Street 2','12344444','Florida, US')  2400.0
2      103  {'Chandler','Bing'}  ...  ('Street 1','12345555','Georgia, US')   601.1
```

Comment: Further continuation to above scenario, can i access  cust_name's first value                        something like this if i want to access only  Tom how do i do that ?

Comment: Output should be                                                                                                                       I want to access first value of a cust_name in above case in first row it is  cust_name[0]  Tom then cust_name[1] 'C'  in second row i want to access 'Rachel'  then 'Green'                 Is there any way to do the same ?

Comment: see this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842372/4985099

Comment: I referred above link ,                                                                           
df['cust_name2'] = df['cust_name'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['cust_name2']                                                                                                                 i get output as below,                                                                                                        0               {C, Tom}
1        {Rachel, Green}
But  i want  first value of row as  C then  2nd as Tom. From 2nd row's 1st value as  Rachel then  2nd value as Green