# convert string to bytes in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

I have column in a csv that has this value as string:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@'
```

How can I convert this string in a bytes object in python?

I tried `bytes(string_var, 'utf-8')` but I got:

```
b"b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xc0\\x99MC@'"
```

I am reading the csv file with pandas

thanks in advance

[edit]

answers to comments:

1- my expected result is: b'\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99MC@' (with only one 'b' and object type as bytes and not string)

2-I got this csv from: sql with byte array column => pandas dataframe => csv file

ps:
before create csv file from pandas I use this command:

blob['Raw'] = blob['Raw'].apply(lambda x: x.tobytes())

otherwise, the csv file will store '<memory at 0x7f697cdc9d08>' string

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: what result do you expect? As for me this is already bytes string - but Python shows it in different way than you probably expect. If it can't display value as char then it display its code - ie. `\x00`

Comment: are you sure you have real `csv` ? How did you create this file? Or where did you get it? maybe it is not `csv` but some `numpy.array` or image.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar is lifesaver

I used [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and worked:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

blob_csv['Raw'] = blob_csv['Raw'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

Thanks to Barmar and [How to use ast.literal_eval in a pandas dataframe and handle exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232742/how-to-use-ast-literal-eval-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-handle-exceptions)