# how to call a function on each group?

Tags: pandas, group-by, grouping

Hi I have a data frame and in one of the columns I have a list of titles. I wrote a function called `find_freq` to find frequency of the elements of these lists. But I need to call this function on each group. Any idea how to call the function on each group `G1` ,`G2` and `G3`?

data:

```
   group                             skill
    G1                              [A,B,C,D]
    G1                              [B,C,K]
    G2                              [A,N,V,B]
    G3                              [B,H,A,D]
    G3                              [A,B,C]
    G3                              [B,C]
```

output:

```
   skill               G1      G2        G3
    A                  1       2         1
    B                  2       2         2
    C                  2       1         2
    D                  1       1         0
    K                  1       0         0
    N                  0       1         0
```

real data:

```
{
 'skill_name': {0: "['Planning', 'Patient Care', 'Design', 'Digital Literacy', 'Business Planning', 'Data Mining', 'Statistical Analysis', 'Data Risk Analysis', 'SQL', 'Creativity', 'Interpersonal', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Science', 'Web Design', 'Business Analysis', 'WordPress', 'Business Strategy', 'Statistics', 'Big Data', 'Legal Documentation', 'Business Data Analytics', 'Business Intelligence', 'Problem Solving', 'Customer Analysis', 'Business Process Analysis', 'Market Analysis', None, 'Online Sales Management', 'Legal Writing', 'Customer Needs Analysis', 'Predictive Modelling', 'Marketing Data Analytics', 'Product Marketing', None]",
  1: "['Financial Management', 'Leadership', 'Reporting', 'Design', 'Statistical Analysis', 'Data Science', 'Business Analysis', 'Data Processing', 'Problem Solving', 'Business Operations', 'Business Process Analysis', 'Executive Management', 'Process Design', 'Framework Design', None, None, None]",
  2: "['Hiring', 'Training', 'Teaching', 'Data Entry', 'Mathematical Modelling', 'Work Collaboratively', None, 'SQL', 'Python', 'Analytical skills', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Science', 'Online Teaching', 'Responsibility', 'Data Research', 'Research', 'Friendly']"},
 'dates': {0: Period('2019-01', 'M'),
  1: Period('2019-01', 'M'),
  2: Period('2019-01', 'M')}}
In [59]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
from pandas import  Period
    
d = {
 'skill_name': {0: "['Planning', 'Patient Care', 'Design', 'Digital Literacy', 'Business Planning', 'Data Mining', 'Statistical Analysis', 'Data Risk Analysis', 'SQL', 'Creativity', 'Interpersonal', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Science', 'Web Design', 'Business Analysis', 'WordPress', 'Business Strategy', 'Statistics', 'Big Data', 'Legal Documentation', 'Business Data Analytics', 'Business Intelligence', 'Problem Solving', 'Customer Analysis', 'Business Process Analysis', 'Market Analysis', None, 'Online Sales Management', 'Legal Writing', 'Customer Needs Analysis', 'Predictive Modelling', 'Marketing Data Analytics', 'Product Marketing', None]",
  1: "['Financial Management', 'Leadership', 'Reporting', 'Design', 'Statistical Analysis', 'Data Science', 'Business Analysis', 'Data Processing', 'Problem Solving', 'Business Operations', 'Business Process Analysis', 'Executive Management', 'Process Design', 'Framework Design', None, None, None]",
  2: "['Hiring', 'Training', 'Teaching', 'Data Entry', 'Mathematical Modelling', 'Work Collaboratively', None, 'SQL', 'Python', 'Analytical skills', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Science', 'Online Teaching', 'Responsibility', 'Data Research', 'Research', 'Friendly']"},
 'dates': {0: Period('2019-01', 'M'),
  1: Period('2019-01', 'M'),
  2: Period('2019-01', 'M')}}
```

---

```
data = pd.DataFrame(d)

import ast
df = (data.assign(skill_name=data['skill_name'].astype(str)
                                               .apply(ast.literal_eval))
          .explode('skill_name'))

print (df.tail(12))
             skill_name    dates
2  Work Collaboratively  2019-01
2                  None  2019-01
2                   SQL  2019-01
2                Python  2019-01
2     Analytical skills  2019-01
2      Machine Learning  2019-01
2          Data Science  2019-01
2       Online Teaching  2019-01
2        Responsibility  2019-01
2         Data Research  2019-01
2              Research  2019-01
2              Friendly  2019-01
```

---

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['skill_name'], df['dates'])
print (df1.head(10))
dates                      2019-01
skill_name                        
Analytical skills                1
Big Data                         1
Business Analysis                2
Business Data Analytics          1
Business Intelligence            1
Business Operations              1
Business Planning                1
Business Process Analysis        2
Business Strategy                1
Creativity                       1
```

print (df1)

```
print (df1)
group  G1  G2  G3
skill            
A       1   1   2
B       2   1   3
C       2   0   2
D       1   0   1
H       0   0   1
K       1   0   0
N       0   1   0
V       0   1   0
```

Last some data cleaning:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: `explode` keeps some `[` and `]`

Comment: @elham edited and afded another solution.

Comment: still get error: `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`

Comment: @elham both solutions failed?

Comment: your first code give me wrong index. the index is the whole list!

Comment: @elham Is possible use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842372/2901002) anch change `df = data.assign(skill=data['skill'].apply(ast.literal_eval)).explode('skill')` to`df = data.assign(skill=data['skill'].apply(f)).explode('skill')`?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` might have a problem with `None` inside the list. With that said, I'm certainly in the lost as where either mine or your solution falls short. There might be trailing spaces that OP overlooked.

Comment: @elham - I try some test and seems necessary converting to `strings` first like `df = data.assign(skill_name=data['skill_name'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)).explode('skill_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(data.explode('skill')
     .groupby('skill')
     ['group'].value_counts()
     .unstack('group', fill_value=0)
)
```

**Note** per comment `skill` column is string type. Try:

```
(data.assign(skill=data['skill'].str[1:-1].str.split(','))
     .explode('skill')
     .groupby('skill')
     ['group'].value_counts()
     .unstack('group', fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: some of `]` remain and it makes mistakes

Comment: @elham `skill` column is string type. Use `str.split` before `explode`. See updated answer.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'asign'

Comment: @elham typo `assign` with two `s`’s.  Fixed

Comment: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 0 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: is there any way I remove all `[` and `]` from a column? I tried `data['skill_name'].replace("[","").replace("]","")` but it didn't work.

Comment: @elham you should include the print out of data.to_dict() for you sample data.

Comment: if you run your code on that, you will see what I mean by extra `[` and `]` in the column

Comment: @elham not the second piece of code, which didn't provide any errors...

Comment: I did some thing with data to remove those `[` and `]` . that's why gave me that error. but you're code still give extra `[` and `]`

Comment: *I did some thing with data to remove those* the second piece of code should remove the `[]` for you. It's really hard to debug any error if you keep adding random code.

Comment: Did you even tried your code on my real data to see how I have the problem with the output! forget about that error. please help me to get the output that I want if you can

Comment: @elham Yes your highness. I did, there is no `[]`, no error.