# Got this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[13 12 12 13 12 12]'

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to load data from a csv file.

There's an object in file as follows:

```
[13 12 12 13 12 12]
```

`dtype('O')` as shown when I tried `object'.values.dtype`

how to convert to numeric list?

Tried `astype(str)`, not working either.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

Comment: You are asking to convert a `array`  to `int`, which won't make sense as an `array` contains `int`, but can't convert `array` itself to `int`.

Comment: @Barmar That object (string?) when passed to ast.literal_eval() raises SyntaxError

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232742/how-to-use-ast-literal-eval-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-handle-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that as a string then:

```
s = '[13 12 12 13 12 12]'

print([int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split()])
```

**Output:**

```
[13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 12]
```